# Bulk changing Base Image

Tags: magento-1.9

How do I change in bulk the base image of a product to an existing image? I have images that were changed from an image to a non-existing (null) image and it made the product page not display the images in the gallery. I've discovered that when an image is set as the base image... the gallery come back. I've tried uploading one through the data flow, but that only creates a new image with the same image. I haven't tried the SQL or ORM route.

Answer (score 0):

We discovered how to do this - instead of using /[image]… you have to use /[image_char1]/[image_char2]/[image]

Where [image_char1] is the first character of the image, [image_char2] is the second character, and [image] is the image filename itself.

Magento treats the image as a location on the media/catalog location of the server rather than on the import section to be added